# JSONparsing in google books api

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am trying to get results from this google books api "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=android&maxResults=20"

The code for Json parsing is

```
try {
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(booksJson);
            JSONArray books = root.getJSONArray("items");
            for (int i = 0; i < books.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject book = books.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject info = book.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
                String title = info.getString("title");
                JSONArray authors = info.getJSONArray("authors");
                String author = authors.getString(0);
                JSONObject imageLinks = info.getJSONObject("imageLinks");
                String imageLink = imageLinks.getString("smallThumbnail");
                Book bookObject = new Book(author,title,imageLink);
                booksList.add(bookObject);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG + " Index :", String.valueOf(i) + "  :  " + String.valueOf(books.length()));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }
```

Problem is that there are 20 results when I check in web browser and it also shows 20 results when I log books.length() in logcat but It skips some books and shows fewer results as expected. Please Help.

Comment: How could you draw the conclusion that you got less result?

Comment: I get less results when I run the app in android emulator

Comment: Then it works well on real device?

Comment: Haven't tried on real device yet

Comment: You say it shows 20 results when you log books.length() so what is the problem?

Comment: sorry it shows the size of books array as 20 in logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got less results because in for loop when you parse the data an exception occurred and you break the for loop . The data showed which the data added to your **booksList** before the exception occurred .

So Debug the for loop to detect which parameter you try to parse and not found so the exception occurred

Thanks

Comment: I have tried debugging. The problem is with authors it skips some authors and store some. when I comment out the authors and insert "" inside my book list it shows 20 list items.

Comment: @AmmarHussain you can use try catch to parse authors . it will work

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. Can you tell me why it worked with try/catch.

Comment: @AmmarHussain try catch will prevent from break from the for loop . Please accept my answer